# Disaster Recovery: Deleted Entire Knowledge Base on Web (Zendesk)

Tags: google-chrome, cache, recovery

Running Chrome **Version 96.0.4664.110 (Official Build) (64-bit)** under **Win10**.

Recently, through user error, we deleted apx. 100 articles from our customer knowledge base, which is hosted by Zendesk. Not one-at-a-time but by deleting the entire **brand** containing the info for our product.

It's uncertain, at best, if Zendesk will recover these valuable articles. So, I've been trying to find cached copies per the link below. I don't know enough about caching to understand if this "data" is stored on my hard drive, in the cloud, or both.

https://www.webnots.com/how-to-view-content-of-cached-page-when-it-is-not-accessible/

I've tried the above solutions (fortunately, I found some URLs from the deleted articles) but to no avail, except possibly for one page, despite uncovering what I hoped were promising URLs.

In fact, options 6 and 7 did not work at all. And it would be nearly impossible to determine the article IDs (which are part of the article URLs) every one of our 100 pages.

At this point, this process feels like a scavenger hunt.

Perhaps I need to approach this problem from another angle? Can anyone offer some additional suggestions? And if I'm lucky enough to find a usable copy of an article, how do I move it from the cache (or other resource) into a live web page?

Many thanks,

Steve

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Maybe it's captured in the Internet Archive?

Answer (score 0):

When you delete a category, all the sections contained in the category
are also deleted, and all the articles contained the sections are archived.
When you delete a section, all the articles contained in the section are
archived.

You cannot recover a deleted Category, but you can recreate it.

A Zendesk article that describes how to recover
archived articles is found here:
[Viewing and restoring archived articles](https://support.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/235721587-Viewing-and-restoring-archived-articles)